# Exclude dynamic region in Animation for plotting a Vector Field

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a vector field and moving circle, but I don't want to plot the vector field inside the circle. Moreover I want to animate the whole thing.
Here is the code I have to plot the vector field on the entire grid.
The variable "positions" contains the coordinates of the circle.
The variable "vectorFields" contains the components of the vector field on the entire grid. How can I exclude this region from plotting the vector field inside it?

```
import matplotlib.animation as anim
X,Y = np.mgrid[-10:10,-10:10]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-10, 10)
ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)
circle1=plt.Circle((positions[0,0,0], positions[0,1,0]),1)
ax.add_patch(circle1)
U=vectorFields[:,:,0,0]
V=vectorFields[:,:,1,0]
q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V)

def animate(i):
   circle1.set_center(positions[0,:,i])


   U=vectorFields[:,:,0,i]
   V=vectorFields[:,:,1,i]
   q.set_UVC(U, V)

   return [circle1]

theAnimation = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=1000, interval=10, blit=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer to my question.
The trick is that one can calculate for each point in the grid the distance to the circle. If the distance is smaller than the radius then one can set the vector field to be zero at that point. This is equivalent to not plotting the vector inside the circle because a vanishing vector doesn't get plotted.

```
for i in range(timesteps):
      centre_x=positions[0,0,i]
      centre_y=positions[0,1,i]
      for k in range(GridMax):
         for l in range(GridMax):
            distance_from_centre=math.sqrt((k-GridMax/2-centre_x)**2+(l-GridMax/2-centre_y)**2)
            if distance_from_centre<=cell.bead_radius:
               vectorFields[k,l,0,i]=0
               vectorFields[k,l,1,i]=0
```